# "How to read strings and numbers from the same file with a while loop in python 3?"

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, while-loop

I am having trouble reading strings and numbers from a file with a while loop. There are imaginary names with their age and number of siblings in a text file. I want to read the names, the age, and the number of siblings in the text file with a while loop. If you need more information to solve the problem let me know. Help is very appreciated

```
outfile = open('practice.txt', 'w')

def main():

    print('this program will print the name and age of a person')

    details()


def details():

    choice = input('Would you like to enter your name, age, and number of siblings? Enter Y for yes and N for no: ')

    while choice != 'N' and choice != 'n':

        name = input('Enter your name: ')
        age = input('Enter your age: ')
        siblings = input('Enter the number of siblings: ')

        outfile.write(name + '\n')
        outfile.write(str(age + '\n'))
        outfile.write(str(siblings + '\n'))

        choice = input('Would you like to continue? Enter Y for yes and N for no: ')

    outfile.close()

main()
```

This code above is the code that allows me to get the information and store it in a text file. The code below is that im working on so i can read from the file.

```
infile = open('practice.txt', 'r')

line = infile.readline()


while line != '':

    line = infile.readline()
    age = int(line)

infile.close()
```

This is what my data file looks like. BELOW

```
joe
56
2
john
27
5
james
14
3
```

Comment: Could you post a code snippet that meets the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Read the file line by line.  For each line split on a useful delimiter, getting a list of strings.  Convert those to numbers as needed.  As with any programming task, start with the small pieces that you know, and build up from there.  At this point we don't know how much Python you know or don't.

Comment: Having trouble in what way? Show us your code, explain your desired result, and how the actual result differs from your expectations.

Comment: How will i be able to post my code?

Comment: @PatrickArtner take a look now

Comment: What does your data file look like?

Comment: @Jaba take a look now

Comment: you write one line with a name. then a line with the age, then the line with the amount of siblings. You only read one thing from the file - over and over again into the same variable that you then try to convert it to int ...  the first thing read is a name - why do that? `joe` is not a number...

Comment: @PatrickArtner im a little confused on what your trying to tell me.

Comment: @LukeBrady i posted the code snippet

Comment: @mypetlion i posted the code

Answer (score 0):

You're writing each value on a line, then when you read it you're only reading one line. Read each line back as you write them

```
with open('practice.txt', 'r') as infile:

    while True:       
        name = infile.readline()
        if not name:
            break
        age = int(infile.readline())
        siblings = int(infile.readline())
```

Comment: I appreciate this! Its just i haven't learned this type of formatting in class and my teacher expects me to use the formatting above to try and solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's ALMOST right, but a few details:

1. Open infile not as `readline()`, but just as "", otherwise, it will skip the first line.
2. Don't test `choice` for "N" and for "n", just do something like `if choice.lower() == "n":`.
3. Also read the siblings, or do something to skip them, otherwise it will confuse the code, as "2" will be read as the line, "john" will be read as the age, but int("john") will spit an error

Answer (score 0):

Since each person takes 3 lines in the file, you need to read 3 lines each time through the loop.

You should also use `rstrip()` to remove the newlines at the end of each line.

```
line = infile.readline()
while line:
    name = line.rstrip()
    line = infile.readline()
    age = int(line.rstrip())
    line = infile.readline()
    siblings = int(line.rstrip())
    # ...
    # do something with `name`, `age`, and `siblings`
    # ...

    line = infile.readline()
```